# How to get just element of array in Java & MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my example for **Product** MongoDB Collection:

```
product {

sku: abcQWE123,
url: www.xyz.com
comments:[
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "inceptos himenaeos",
    "viverra. Aenean placerat ex in justo ul"
]

}
```

I want to get just a comment with "**url**" if it consist "**ipsum**".

Imagine that if database had a just entry which is above, my result would have been like this:

```
product{

url: www.xyz.com
comments:[
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
]

}
```

I can get whole entries which contain "**ipsum**", using commands at below. But I want to be specific although I don't know how to do it. Could you help me about this subject?

```
public void main(String[] args) {

    MongoCursor<Product> p = mongoDB.getProducts().find(myMongoFilter("comments", "ipsum")).iterator();
    
    try {
        while (p.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(p.next().toString());
        }
    } finally {
        p.close();
    }

}

public Document myMongoFilter(String myField, String myRegex) {
    return new Document(myField, new Document("$regex", myRegex));
}
```

Comment: You need the comments with "impsum" in it and the respective URL??

Comment: @KaranGaur yes, I want to do it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the my answer. @Sumanth229 thank you for mentioning the algorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    ...
    List<Document> products = mongoDB.getProductsInRaw().aggregate(Filter.findComments("ipsum")).into(new ArrayList<>());

    products.forEach(document -> System.out.println(document.toJson()));
    ...
    ...
}

public MongoCollection<Products> getProducts() {
    return getDB().getCollection("products", Products.class);
}

public MongoCollection<Document> getProductsInRaw() {
    return getDB().getCollection("products");
}

public static ArrayList<Bson> findComments(String keywords) {
    ArrayList<Bson> queries = new ArrayList<>();
    queries.add(Filter.aggregateContains("comments", keywords));
    queries.add(Filter.aggregateUnwind("comments"));
    queries.add(Filter.aggregateContains("comments", keywords));

    //
    // To access full question's answer, remove comment block.
    // I don't want to use this line because of my requests were changed.
    // queries.add(new Document("$group", new Document("_id", new Document("comments", "$comments").append("url", "$url")).append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))));
    //
    //

    return queries;
}

public static Document aggregateContains(String field, String regex) {
    return new Document("$match", new Document(field, new Document("$regex", regex)));
}

public static Document aggregateUnwind(String field) {
    return new Document("$unwind", "$" + field);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like this using projections in mongo

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;

MongoCursor<Product> p = mongoDB.getProducts()
                                .find(myMongoFilter("comments", "ipsum"))
                                .projection(Projections.include("comments", "url"))
                                .iterator();
```

Comment: Hi, your contribution does not working totally what I want to see. Yes, it masks the SKU field, but other comments do not go anywhere.

Comment: you have to unwind the comments list and then filter and group it back using MongoDB aggregation to show only the comments with ipsum in it.

Comment: If you have a code-solution, could you share with me? By the way, thank you for sharing algorithm, I am going to searching it that how to do it.